# How to store and display scores at the end of a quiz

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've got a simple quiz program that selects 10 random questions from the database and presents it to the user. At the end of the quiz when the user cicks on submit, i'd like to **display the score to the user.**

Below is a snippet of the code that runs the quizz

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class serv3p extends HttpServlet    
{

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)    
                     throws ServletException, IOException    
    {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        String qKey = req.getParameter("sQuestionID");
        int iQuestionID = Integer.parseInt(qKey);


        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String sourceURL = new String("jdbc:odbc:MyQuiz");//DSN name
            Connection databaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(sourceURL);
            if (databaseConnection != null)
                out.println("<P>Connection made<BR>");

            if (iQuestionID < 11) out.println("QuestionID is: " + qKey);
            Statement myStatement = databaseConnection.createStatement();
            ResultSet results = myStatement.executeQuery ("SELECT TOP 10 QuestionBank.QuestionText, QuestionBank.Choice1, QuestionBank.Choice2,"
            +"QuestionBank.Choice3, QuestionBank.Choice4,QuestionBank.Answer FROM QuestionBank ORDER BY RND(QuestionID)");



            //ResultSet results = myStatement.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM QuestionBank WHERE QuestionID = '"+qKey+"'");

            if (results.next())
                {
                String r1, r2, r3, r4, r5;
                r1 = results.getString(1);
                r2 = results.getString(2);
                r3 = results.getString(3);
                r4 = results.getString(4);
                r5 = results.getString(5);
                //r6 = results.getString(6);
                out.println("<BODY BGCOLOR='lightblue'></BODY>" +
                    "<FORM method = \"post\" action = \"http://localhost:8080/servlet/Relay\">" +
                    "<TABLE BORDER = 2 CELLPADDING = 4 CELLSPACING = 2>" +
                    "<TR><TD COLSPAN = 6 ALIGN = CENTER><H2><B>Quick Quizz : Sports</B></H2></TD></TR>");
                out.println("<TR><TD>" + r1 + "</TD></TR>");
                out.println("<TR><TD><input type = \"radio\" name = \"answer\" value = \"1\">" + r2 + "</TD></TR><BR>");
                out.println("<TR><TD><input type = \"radio\" name = \"answer\" value = \"2\">" + r3 + "</TD></TR><BR>");
                out.println("<TR><TD><input type = \"radio\" name = \"answer\" value = \"3\">" + r4 + "</TD></TR><BR>");
                out.println("<TR><TD><input type = \"radio\" name = \"answer\" value = \"4\">" + r5 + "</TD></TR><BR>");
                out.println("</TABLE>");
                results.close();
                iQuestionID++; qKey = "" + iQuestionID;
                out.println("<BR>End of Database Records<BR>");
                if (iQuestionID < 11)

                    {
                    out.println("<BR><BR><INPUT type = \"submit\" value = \"Press for Next Question\">" +
                                "<INPUT type = \"hidden\" name = \"sQuestionID\" value = '" + qKey + "'><p>" +
                                "<INPUT type = \"hidden\" name = \"choice\" value = \"Play\"></FORM></BODY></HTML>");
                    }

                else
                    {out.println("<BR><BR><INPUT type = \"submit\" value = \"Press to Exit\">" +
                                 "<INPUT type = \"hidden\" name = \"sQuestionID\" value = '" + qKey + "'><p>" +
                                 "<INPUT type = \"hidden\" name = \"choice\" value = \"serv43a\"></FORM></BODY></HTML>");

                    }
                out.close();
                }
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
                {System.out.println(cnfe);}
            catch(SQLException sqle)
                {System.out.println("Error is: " + sqle);}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the database to store the calculated score, and then display it on the results page? If you don't need to keep the scores for any length of time (e.g. longer than an hour or so), you can always check for, and delete old records as often as necessary.

Comment: so in my database, i will have something like ScoreTable with QuestionID,Answer,AnswerValue fields. At the moment i do not have a results page. Can you please explain to me how to go about that.Thank you

Comment: How are you handling moving from question to question? Whatever that method is, I would say you could use something similar to go to the results page when you're done.

Comment: ok i'll use that same method. problem is how to calculate the score.

Comment: If you're storing the answers in the database, I suppose you could simply store whether the answer was correct or not, and then calculate the answer from that. It's going to be some combination of storing the answers, followed by doing a query to get the summary results (e.g. 7/10 questions correct), and then calculating a score from that.

Answer (score 0):

Well the question you should ask yourself is, do i want to keep the scores for an amount of time ( for an example: a poll ), or do you just want to use it as a Test like  software wich returns the exact score after the test, but than just destroys that value together with the end of the software,

if you do want to keep it for a longer amount of time, you could write all values in an access database, or even an SQL server,

if you think the values you want to keep aren't that mutch, than i'd sugest you write it down in a txt based file, since it is easy to store and doesn't take as much time as a database connection to write it away,

to get at your score you will need to hardcode the right answers, with swich cases or if/else, just hardcode the place of your string with te correct answer, and add the score to a private int (or float/double)

displaying it is not that hard, if you want to display the stuff from plenty op participants, just use an enhanced for loop, with a println wich displays the name of the participant and the numbers, or even put it in a JFrame. thats up to you,

---

my advise

( a lot of data you want to keep ) => SQL / (access) databases

( a bit of data you want to keep ) => txt File and if you know the exact number of participants ( XML )

( just diplay ) print your score,

you will need to hardcode this score, and that depends on how you chose the values.

---

final tip: Dont open too many db connections it will only slow your progress down, and stuff like the right answer are easy to hard code since they are not variable, and you only have like 10 questions

---

Question 1: (edit)

no problem, you only want like 10 Questions right, cause i discussed the problem with a friend of mine last night, and if you do want to keep the scores for a longer amount of time, you might want to have the possibility to add more questions if not,

just use the if else way for each question

if(Question1.equals("Question1"))
{
    no problem, you only want like 10 Questions right, cause i discussed the problem with a friend of mine last night, and if you do want to keep the scores for a longer amount of time, you might want to have the possibility to add more questions if not,

just use the if else way for each question

if(Question1.equals("Question1"))

{

Switch(answer)

case 1: points++; break;

case 2: break;

case 3: break;

default: break;

}

}

else

{

if(Question2.equals("Question2"))

{

Switch(answer)

case 1: break;

case 2: points++; break;

case 3: break;

default: break;

}

else

{

}

}

and so on, fill in the Questions like this,

String Question = "Question1";

if ( Question.equals("Question1"))
{
    ...
}

if you do wish to do it with a database, you can as well put the answer in an extra attribute, and than you could do it like this

int[] answerOnTheQuestions  = the answers from the test ( put them in an Int array )
int[] answers = ( your db link to the right table and column here ) 
int score = 0;

for ( int counter = 0; counter < questions.length; counter ++)

{

if( answersOnTheQuestions[counter] == answers[counter] )

{

score++;

}

}

Write score to your table together with like a participants name that you can get in the GUI or consle.

I hope this helped :)

Comment: thank you very much I think i'll go the sql/ database way because i'll also like to view all scores as an administrator. If its not much of a bother, can you please give me an example of how to hard code the right answers using if statements

Comment: if it helped please do accept the answer ^^ good luck with your project i hope it helped  ( edited my answer

Comment: Thanks once again. i think i'll take the database suggestion. This is how my database is organised

Comment: Thanks once again. i think i'll take the database suggestion. This is how my database is organised  into 7   columns ie **QuestionID  QuestionText Choice1 Choice2 Choice3 Choice4 Answer**   Do you think it'll work like that. I'm going to try it anyway

Comment: well i think it will work like that, just put all of the fields in an array, and use the ID's to determine the array place ( Don't forget ) if you want to write away your index in the db, or get an id out of your table( Array starts on 0, tables start on 1 ), better yet use a 2 dim array, like [ID][NeededItem] in a double for loop this shouldn't be a problem